# SQL Query: Using Cursors

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

I need some directions for SQL Server & Cursors:

I have a table named Order:

```
OrderID   Item   Amount
1         A      10
1         B      1
2         A      5
2         C      4
2         D      21
3         B      11
```

I have a second table named Storage:

```
   Item   Amount
   A      40
   B      44
   C      20
   D      1
```

For every OrderID, I want to check if enough items are available. If not, I want to return an error message. How can this be done with Cursors at all? Are nested cursors the solution to this? My main issue is to understand how I can fetch the OrderID as actual "Group" of ID=1, 2, 3 etc. instead of line by line

Comment: Do you really need cursor to solve your problem?

Comment: Is is compulsary that you use cursors? In general you should use a set-bases approach like `Select OrderID, 'Error, not enough in store' from Order, Storage where Order.Item = Storage.Item and Order.Amount > Storage.Amount`

Comment: ah no cursor required at all! thanks alot luigi, that seems to do the trick!:) just one more question: I'm going for a stored procedure to perform the orders. is it possible to stop the specific order once the mentioned error (insufficient stock) occurs?

Comment: Try WHILE / BREAK statements.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use a cursor.  You could use a try / catch if you need to throw an error.